# Unable to dynamically change KDE Plasma 5 Widget Expandable FullRepresentation Component size outside of Component.onCompleted

Tags: qml, kde-plasma, plasmoid

I'm coding a widget that can be expanded to its FullRepresentation by being clicked on:

```
                onClicked: {
                    plasmoid.expanded = !plasmoid.expanded 
                }
```

I have a function that updates its contents and puts them into a Gridview. The update function is first called from Component.onCompleted, but then I call it every time the user updates the data. The problem is the data I feed into the expandable FullRepresentation can contain a varying number of elements that I put into the gridview and calculate its AND the FullRepresentation's sizes based on this number.

However, I find I'm only able to specify the Representation's size from the Component.onCompleted block. When I call the update function outside it, it doesn't change the size, no matter whether the size is defined in the item properties like so:

```
Item 
{
    id: fullRepresentation
    width: no_items > 2 ? 465 : no_items * 155
    height: Math.ceil(no_items / 3)* 155    
    property int no_items
```

...and I only try to change the no_items property from the UpdateFunction, or just try to run the two equations from it.

Is there any way around this? I've also tried the implicitHeight and implicitWidth properties. I really would like to be able to dynamically adjust the size of the main expandable representation, it feels bad to have to hardcode it and then have a lot of unfilled space.

EDIT:
Here is the requested example:

*Root.qml*

```
import org.kde.plasma.plasmoid 2.0
import QtQuick 2.2

Item
{
    id: root
    width: 185; height: 185
    Plasmoid.compactRepresentation: Compact {}
    Plasmoid.fullRepresentation: Full {}
    Plasmoid.preferredRepresentation: Plasmoid.compactRepresentation
    signal addItems() 
}
```

*Compact.qml*

```
import QtQuick 2.2

Item
{
    Rectangle
    {      
        width: root.width; height: root.height
        MouseArea
        {
            anchors.fill: parent
            acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton | Qt.RightButton
            onClicked: if (mouse.button == Qt.RightButton) root.addItems()
                       else plasmoid.expanded = !plasmoid.expanded
        }
    }
}
```

*Full.qml*

```
import QtQuick 2.2

Item 
{
    width: no_items > 2 ? 465 : no_items * 155
    height: Math.ceil(no_items / 3)* 155    
    property int no_items : 0
    function redrawGridView()  
    {        
        readingListModel.clear()       
        var i
        for (i = 0; i < no_items; i++) readingListModel.append({})                
    }     
    function addItems()
    {
        no_items = 6
        width = no_items > 2 ? 465 : no_items * 155
        height = Math.ceil(no_items / 3)* 155    
        redrawGridView()
    }

    ListModel 
    {
        id: readingListModel
    }

    GridView 
    { 
        id: readingGridView
        width: count > 2 ? 465 : count * 155
        height: Math.ceil(count/3) * 155
        cellWidth: 155; cellHeight: 155
        model: readingListModel
        delegate: Rectangle
        {                  
            width: 150; height: 150;
        }
    }

   Component.onCompleted:
    {            
        root.addItems.connect(addItems)    
        no_items = 3  
        redrawGridView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've added the example :)

Comment: By the way, the same thing happens with other items, including the Root item. This causes another bug: now I've added the option to switch between the Full and Compact representations (with the Compact still containing the expandable Full one). But on switching them, the size stays the same and if we start with Full as default, Compact will be too large, if we start with Compact, switch to Full and back to Compact, the expandable's size is somehow set to the size of the Compact item anyway.

Comment: @folibis Can I have an answer on this please? I'm a beginner to QML and tutorials for the language are scarce so I don't know whether it's possible to dynamically modify the core Item size or just not. Surely that isn't a difficult question to answer for a professional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got no answer but I've figured this out myself.
Indeed, this doesn't seem to be possible using the plasmoid.expanded method with the Full Representation, and produces other bugs, as I mentioned in my comment.

But you can dynamically resize a Window item size from anywhere in your code, so this works just fine:

*in Compact.qml*

```
    Full
    {  
        id: fullRep
    }  
    MouseArea
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: 
        {
            if (!fullRep.visible) fullRep.show()
            else fullRep.close()
        }
    }
```

*start of Full.qml*

```
Window
{
    x: 100;y: 100
    width: 465;height: 195
    color: theme.backgroundColor
    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint //You can make it frameless like the expandable  
                                 //representation is when using the previous method
```